# Formatear rut con puntos y guión en JavaScript simple

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, regex

Necesito que cuando el cliente va presionando el teclado para digitar su número de RUT o DNI, el sistema vaya agregando automáticamente los puntos y el guión, Pero cabe recordar que no todos los ruts tienen 8 dígitos sino que algunos tienen 9 y es eso que se debe tomar en cuenta.

Tengo el siguiente JavaScript simple pero solo funciona con ruts de 9 dígitos y no los de 8 dígitos:

```html
<input type="text" class="inputs" name="rut" id="rut" 
    onkeydown = "this.value = this.value.replace
    ( /^(\d{1})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\w{1})$/, '$2.$2.$3-$4')" >
```

¿Alguna idea de cómo se puede hacer?

Comment: Entiendo tu pregunta, y tengo una solución pero me gustaria saber si estas de acuerdo en utilizar una libreria de terceros para esto? Recomiendo hacerlo asi porque la solución es mas simple y mas mantenible.

Comment: uso jquery de momento

Comment: @NICALANICA Por favor completa el [tour] para aprender cómo funciona el sitio en general y también lee [esta página del centro de ayuda](/help/be-nice) con el comportamiento esperado por parte de los usuarios. Un saludo.

Answer (score 4):

Una forma para que "***vaya agregando automaticamente los puntos y el guion***", podría ser la siguiente.

```js
document.getElementById('rut').addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
  let value = this.value.replace(/\./g, '').replace('-', '');
  
  if (value.match(/^(\d{2})(\d{3}){2}(\w{1})$/)) {
    value = value.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\w{1})$/, '$1.$2.$3-$4');
  }
  else if (value.match(/^(\d)(\d{3}){2}(\w{0,1})$/)) {
    value = value.replace(/^(\d)(\d{3})(\d{3})(\w{0,1})$/, '$1.$2.$3-$4');
  }
  else if (value.match(/^(\d)(\d{3})(\d{0,2})$/)) {
    value = value.replace(/^(\d)(\d{3})(\d{0,2})$/, '$1.$2.$3');
  }
  else if (value.match(/^(\d)(\d{0,2})$/)) {
    value = value.replace(/^(\d)(\d{0,2})$/, '$1.$2');
  }
  this.value = value;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="inputs" name="rut" id="rut" maxlength="12">
```

Answer (score -1):

Ojo con esta, no me deja borrar de forma normal.

```js
document.getElementById('rut').addEventListener('input', function(evt) {
  let value = this.value.replace(/\./g, '').replace('-', '');
  
  if (value.match(/^(\d{2})(\d{3}){2}(\w{1})$/)) {
    value = value.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\w{1})$/, '$1.$2.$3-$4');
  }
  else if (value.match(/^(\d)(\d{3}){2}(\w{0,1})$/)) {
    value = value.replace(/^(\d)(\d{3})(\d{3})(\w{0,1})$/, '$1.$2.$3-$4');
  }
  else if (value.match(/^(\d)(\d{3})(\d{0,2})$/)) {
    value = value.replace(/^(\d)(\d{3})(\d{0,2})$/, '$1.$2.$3');
  }
  else if (value.match(/^(\d)(\d{0,2})$/)) {
    value = value.replace(/^(\d)(\d{0,2})$/, '$1.$2');
  }
  this.value = value;
});
```

```html
<input type="text" class="inputs" name="rut" id="rut" maxlength="12">
```

Comment: ¿Esto es una respuesta? ¿Un comentario? ¿Otra pregunta? Lee [answer] y haz el [tour] para conocer el funcionamiento del sitio.

Answer (score -4):

Dejaré la respuesta correcta aquí mismo para los que necesiten algo bueno para ruts chilenos:

```
<input type="text" class="inputs" 
name="cliente" id="cliente" 
maxlength="12" onkeyup="formatCliente(this)">
//importante que el id sea el correcto
//importante que por ser ruts chilenos no tengan mas de 12 caracteres de largo

<script type="text/javascript">
function formatCliente(cliente)
{cliente.value=cliente.value.replace(/[.-]/g, '')
.replace( /^(\d{1,2})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\w{1})$/, '$1.$2.$3-$4')}
</script>
```

y listo ya lo tenemos funcionando de forma sencilla, al tipear se ira formando solo el rut con sus puntos y guion correspondiente sin importar la cantidad de dígitos del rut.