# Como enviar el nombre del v-model no su valor

Tags: javascript, vue.js

Tengo la siguiente duda, estoy con Vuejs, tengo un [método](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/157763/formatear-rut-con-puntos-y-gui%C3%B3n-en-javascript-simple) para formatear el rut cuando se ingresa (on-keyup)

```js
    formatRut(rut) {
      let value = this.rutEmpresa.replace(/\./g, '').replace('-', '')
      if (value.match(/^(\d{2})(\d{3}){2}(\w{1})$/)) {
        value = value.replace(/^(\d{2})(\d{3})(\d{3})(\w{1})$/, '$1.$2.$3-$4')
      } else if (value.match(/^(\d)(\d{3}){2}(\w{0,1})$/)) {
        value = value.replace(/^(\d)(\d{3})(\d{3})(\w{0,1})$/, '$1.$2.$3-$4')
      } else if (value.match(/^(\d)(\d{3})(\d{0,2})$/)) {
        value = value.replace(/^(\d)(\d{3})(\d{0,2})$/, '$1.$2.$3')
      } else if (value.match(/^(\d)(\d{0,2})$/)) {
        value = value.replace(/^(\d)(\d{0,2})$/, '$1.$2')
      }
      this.rutEmpresa = value
    },
```

Funciona perfecto, pero tengo 2 variables que pueden usar este método, rutEmpresa y rutRepresentante; No sé como hacer para poder reutilizar el método.

Muchas gracias!

Qué necesito: Poder usar el método formatRut con dos variables diferentes (dos inputs) rutEmpresa (como se ve en el ejemplo) y rutRepresentante

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: deber especificar que tipo de formato desea sacar por ejemplo el RUT se componer de # - # ### ###  , si desea sacar dese un input el formato de RUT puede utilizar la siguiente librería https://www.npmjs.com/package/v-mask